# oscommerce redirect multiple - root to folder, folder to folder + www to non www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, oscommerce

I'm trying to redirect multiple situation to my oscommerce store located in a folder
mydomain.com/osc without www

Please help me in redirecting...

My OSC is installed in a folder /store/
I want all domain.com or www.domain.com to redirect to domain.com/store
also permanent redirect old domain folder /shop/ with or www to /store/

I've tried it but a strange issue appears, it work fine for products but when I access info pages with www.domain.com/store/contact_us.php it redirect to domain.com/contact_us.php and give 404 error (ofcourse there is nothig)

here is .htaccess of my root (domain.com)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://ambiancehome.ca/store/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.com/store [R=301,L]

#additional redirect of a product which is moved/removed / changed
Redirect 301 /store/bed-loungers-c-21.html http://ambiancehome.ca/store/product_info.php/bed-lounge-back-rest-reading-pillow-p-104.html
```

Here is .htaccess of /store/ folder

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# RewriteBase instructions
# Change RewriteBase dependent on how your shop is accessed as below.
# http://www.mysite.com = RewriteBase /
# http://ambiancehome.ca/store/ = RewriteBase /store/
# http://www.mysite.com/catalog/shop/ = RewriteBase /catalog/shop/
# Change RewriteBase using the instructions above
RewriteBase /store/
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-p-([0-9]+).html$ product_info.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-c-([0-9_]+).html$ index.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-m-([0-9]+).html$ index.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-pi-([0-9]+).html$ popup_image.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-pr-([0-9]+).html$ product_reviews.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-pri-([0-9]+).html$ product_reviews_info.php [NC,L,QSA]
# Articles contribution
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-t-([0-9_]+).html$ articles.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-au-([0-9]+).html$ articles.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-a-([0-9]+).html$ article_info.php [NC,L,QSA]
# Information pages
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-i-([0-9]+).html$ information.php [NC,L,QSA]
# Links contribution
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-links-([0-9_]+).html$ links.php [NC,L,QSA]
# Newsdesk contribution
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-n-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_info.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-nc-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_index.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-nri-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_reviews_info.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-nra-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_reviews_article.php [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your root .htaccess just like this only:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ /store/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: because after using this I'm still able to directly access www.domain.com/store/

Comment: I didn't see this requirement of blocking direct access to /store url in your question. If you clarify all these requirements clearly in your question then I can edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: You wrote in your question: `My OSC is installed in a folder /store/ I want all domain.com or www.domain.com to redirect to domain.com/store also permanent redirect old domain folder /shop/ with or www to /store/` After this I did't understand your comment that **`I'm still able to directly access www.domain.com/store/`**